# missing rows of data in SAS

Tags: sas

I wrote the following:

```
libname learn 'C:\Users\PCPCPC\Documents\sasdeposite';
data learn.test_score;
length ID $ 3 Name $ 15;
input ID $ Score1-Score3;
label ID = 'Student ID'
score1= 'Math Score'
score2= 'Science Score'
Score3= 'English Score';

datalines;
1 90 95 98
2 78 77 75
3 88 91 92
;

proc print 
data = learn.test_scores;
run;
```

I expect they displayed table to show three rows of data, but I only saw one row:

[image]

Comment: your dataset names are different. One you create is learn.test_score and you proc print learn.test_scores. Also your name column is  not there datalines.

Answer (score 1):

Your code generates errors as @Kiran indicated so you should fix those, but once those are fixed it works as expected.

```
data test_score;
length ID $ 3 Name $ 15;
input ID $ Score1-Score3;
label ID = 'Student ID'
score1= 'Math Score'
score2= 'Science Score'
Score3= 'English Score';

datalines;
1 90 95 98
2 78 77 75
3 88 91 92
;

proc print 
data = test_score;
run;
```